# Loopback - mapping /user/login to /login

Tags: redirect, loopback

For the purposes of a published API, I would like to direct the client to /api/login to login rather than /api/user/login

The login process works perfectly when /api/user/login is called - 
My question:  is it simple to map this functionality to a /api/login URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your custom [middleware in loopback](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-middleware.html), as it follows Express' routes, you could intercept the call to `/login` and redirect to a model of your preference. Also, you could create a model named `Login`, and call the corresponding [remote method](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html) in your User's model.